# Postgres Json List of Map

Tags: json, postgresql

I have one sample json as below

```json
{
    "jsonObject":
        [ 
            { "Name" : "XPerson",
                "Age"  : 18},
            { "Name" : "YPerson",
                "Age"  : 18}
        ]
}
```

I can have this list to N numbers. I want to separate this in different column based on Age like less than 18 in  column1, between 18 to 25 in column2 and all other in column3.

How can we achieve in postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to do front end's job at database level.

```
with data(Age,Name) as
         (select *
          from jsonb_to_recordset(' {
            "jsonObject": [
              {
                "Name": "XPerson",
                "Age": 18
              },
              {
                "Name": "YPerson",
                "Age": 18
              }
            ]
          }'::jsonb -> 'jsonObject') as t("Age" int, "Name" text))
select
        string_agg(case when  age < 18 then name end,',') as Column1,
        string_agg(case when  age >= 18 and age <=25 then name end,',') as Column2,
        string_agg(case when  age > 25 then name end,',') as Column3
from data;
```

Comment: We have used two select statement here, what if we have other data as ID being a separate column than json column.

Comment: @Pallavkalal, you would also include that. You may ask that as another question giving sample data and explaining what you require.